# white space shows charecter in xcode file?

Tags: xcode8

[image]

I tried but not able to find why space become (_) character in my xcode 8.2 swift file.

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open Xcode , and Choose **Editor** :

[image]

And then If **Hide Invisible** is there like this :

[image]

Just Click on **Hide Invisible** and it changes into **Show Invisible**

That solve your issue .

Comment: Thank You Shobhakar Tiwari :)